# Oracle Julian day of year

Tags: sql, oracle, julian-date

how can I select Julian day of year in Oracle database?

I tried:
    select to_char(sysdate, 'J') from dual;
Which gives me the number of days since January 1, 4712 BC. But I would need the number of days since 1.1. of current year.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you check the [TO_CHAR (datetime)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) documentation you get a link to ["Format Models"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510) with a comprehensive list of available formats. I guess you want this:

> `DDD` Day of year (1-366)

Comment: Does this also work for Julian calendar? So is Julian day of year the same as Gregorian day of year?

Comment: Do you want julian day (commonly used in factories for e.g. lot codes) or Julian calendar (the calendar obsoleted by Pope Gregory)? They're entirely different things.

Comment: Yes it will be used for lot code and I found that julian day is the same as day of year by Gregorian calendar. So your answer is correct.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Day of year is probably the same concept in any calendar (Julian, Gregorian, Chinese, Roman...) because it's a simple count: 1, 2, 3...

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DDD') from DUAL;
```

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use:

```
select sysdate - trunc(sysdate,'yyyy') from dual
```

'Trunc' cuts everything except the year and returns 01/01/2014, subtracted by the sysdate returns numbers of days since 1st of january.

Comment: Yes, but not in Julian calendar? Or does it?
If this is the case I can just use:
select to_char(sysdate, 'DDD') from dual;

Comment: You should add `+1` to that expression as yours starts counting days at `0`

Answer (score 1):

Use `sql select trunc(sysdate)+1 - trunc(sysdate,'yyyy') from dual`. you will get an even number